# How did Cochrane obtain dilithium for the first warp flight?

Tags: star-trek, technology, warp, star-trek-first-contact

In the *Star Trek Illustrated Handbook* (based on *The Official Star Trek Fact Files* 1997 - 2002) I read:

> Following the model established by Zefram Cochrane, Federation vessels' warp engines accomplish the transition into subspace by using a matter-antimatter reaction to generate a series of warp fields that exert force against one another.

It goes on to state just how this works:

> In the simplest terms, the warp core works by burning deuterium to create gases, which are then forced together with antimatter in the form of antihydrogen. The reaction is controlled by dilithium crystals to create a plasma stream that is split in two and routed to the warp nacelles. In the nacelles, the plasma is used to energize the warp field coils, made of verterium cortenide.

From numerous episodes, we learn that naturally occurring dilithium is extremely rare and is mined on only a few planets, such as Coridan, Troyius and Rura Penthe. So I wonder, how did Cochrane obtain dilithium to make the first warp flight? Or, what can we speculate is the most probable alternative mechanism that could still make the first warp drive function, lacking dilithium? By the same token, based on the description given above, I can ask the same question about the crystals verterium and cortenide. I guess the latter materials are somewhat less essential, but they appear also not too readily available, cf. e.g. ST VOY s 2, ep 20.

Of course, I want to exclude the very paradoxical explanation that he obtained the material(s) from the Enterprise in *First Contact*.

Comment: If it follows the same patterns as real materials, "verterium cortenide" would probably be a single compound, not two different crystals.

Comment: Note that there's nothing in the lore that requires the use of a dilithium regulated matter-antimatter annihilation reaction to power a warp drive, and there's concrete evidence that there are other ways to do it (the Romulans use some sort of singularity-based power plant for theirs for example). The fact that it's the only widely used approach just indicates that it's the best option from an engineering perspective (though that's questionable in it's own right for other reasons).

Comment: Also, as David Z speculated, verterium cortenide is a "usually synthetically generated compound, the only known substance to be capable of generating warp fields, when supplied with energy, in form of plasma, from the warp core. Warp coils are made of this material," according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Also related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/when-did-dilithium-crystals-become-so-important-for-starships?rq=1

Comment: I feel like they "dumb it down" for the general reader; actual use of dilithium crystals is really complex and much can go wrong.

Comment: TIL Warp engines are steam-powered (since the "gas" produced by burning deuterium would be heavy water).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn that's right. Most cars in our own world don't run on jet fuel not because it's not possible to make a jet fuel-powered car, but because gasoline and diesel are considered better options. A team of engineers in a post-apocalyptic society inhabiting an old airport could plausibly cobble together a jet fuel-powered car if it was important enough for them to do so and they had enough resources in reasonable reach.

Answer (score 40):

Cochrane didn't need dilithium to use as the power source for his warp experiment. He used a 'nuclear power core' to create the energy required.

> The nuclear core in the missile: it was the same fuel his theoretical warp engine required, was it not? Why not beat that damned sword into a plowshare and use the bomb to make an actual ship that he could test?
>
> ...  [later]
>
> He spoke swiftly, happily, of how the nuclear core contained in an old
> warhead could be harnessed for something he called a “warp engine,”
> and he traced in the dirt some mathematical equations to prove it.
>
> <sub><sup>[First Contact - Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact_(novel))</sup></sub>

Admittedly the Enterprise may have helped him with some modern/replicated tech to replace the bits were damaged in the Borg's raid, but that doesn't create a bootstrap paradox because *Cochrane already had the means to go to warp before they intervened.* Their intervention allowed a pre-existing event to take place.

Comment: There’s something wrong with a government that lets chaotic people like Cochrane and friends (as portrayed in ST:FC) have a nuclear core.  That’s right down there with letting Gaius Baltar have one *on a civilian ship in an apartment shared with a Six are you kidding me?*

Comment: @Harper: I'm not entirely familiar with this part of *Star Trek*'s history, but based on their reaction to seeing the Borg ("It's the ECON!"), I'm somewhat skeptical that they *had* a fully functional government at this point.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - There's probably enough nuclear materials to create a crude nuclear bomb at 100 universities around the world.

Comment: Indeed... "What government?"

Comment: _"Their intervention allowed a pre-existing event to take place."_ [citation needed] In fact, a Starfleet officer from the far future, serving aboard a ship equipped with fancy temporal scanners, did joke that the Federation owed its existence to the Borg.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica at the time Cochrane was working on his warp drive, [World War III](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/World_War_III) had just ended and there weren't a lot of governments left. No one "let" him have anything, there was just no one to stop him, and plenty of surplus nukes lying around.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings - it doesn't appear to be a bootstrap paradox. We know that Cochrane was able to create a warp-capable spaceship. The Borg's temproral incursion changed the timeline and the Enterprise's incursion seems to have (largely) changed it back again

Comment: @Valorum Still waiting for the citation. ;) We have no idea how events would have transpired without the interruption of the Borg and Enterprise crew; Cochrane was pretty drunk. The only real evidence I can recall for it not being a causal loop is the appearance of Earth changing from the perspective of the Enterprise while it was caught in the temporal wake, but that could just as easily be interpreted as viewing the result of a partially completed temporal incursion from their point of view. As I say, other than that, I'm going off what an actual in-universe time expert said.

Comment: All that proves is the Borg can drive a person to drink :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings - It makes no logical sense for the Enterprise/Borg to have been necessary for First Contact to have taken place. The event is extremely well researched in-universe and if there was a technical reason why the Phoenix would not have worked *as designed by Cochrane* then surely La Forge would know about it.

Comment: @Valorum I never said anything about technical reasons for the Phoenix "not working". I won't say again that you're literally contradicting a canon statement by an in-universe expert without providing any concrete evidence; I shall just bid you a good day.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The expert doesn't make the claim - a *non-expert* does, and the expert then makes (and then laughs at) a quick quip/joke. The timestamp is about 26:30 into VOY: Relativity.  We know that the Timeline can be permanently changed (allowing for the possibility of the original Phoenix flight to have occurred without Borg presence), as shown in TNG: Time Squared.  Essentially, you can then have a non-bootstrapped lead-in to what later becomes a temporal loop, like launching a particle into a synchrotron with a linear accelerator, and then keeping it looping.

Comment: @Chronocidal Eh? No. Ducane teaches Seven things, then tests her knowledge on those things. One she recounts as: _"The Borg once travelled back in time to stop Zefram Cochrane from breaking the warp barrier. They succeeded, but that in turn led the starship Enterprise to intervene. They assisted Cochrane with the flight the Borg was trying to prevent. **Causal loop complete.**"_ He then states _"So, in a way, the Federation owes its existence to the Borg."_. That's a direct quote. Where's the "quick quip/joke"? You're reaching.

Comment: @Chronocidal And even if you weren't ... there is _still_ no evidence for Valorum's unqualified claim in this answer _"that doesn't create a bootstrap paradox because Cochrane already had the means to go to warp before they intervened. Their intervention allowed a pre-existing event to take place"_. Nobody seems to want to respond to my very simple request for any evidence for that. Interesting.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The Borg enacted their plan to assimilate Earth as an end result of Q's interference with the USS Enterprise-D.  This event did not take place in the Mirror Universe (the Terran Empire had been overthrown and replaced by the Klingon-Cardassian Alliance in 2295) so the Borg had no motive to use Time Travel to stop First Contact, and yet Zephram Cochrane still made a successful Warp Flight (ENT: In a Mirror, Darkly).  (And the quip *is* "So, in a way, the Federation owes its existence to the Borg", which he laughs at mere seconds later)

Comment: The nuclear power core wouldn't have been used in place of the dilithium. Dilithium isn't a power source.

Comment: Just curious if anyone knows how the events in Discovery season 3 happen then? As I understand it the Burn destroyed dilithium making warp travel very scarce afterwards. If there exist other methods of achieving warp travel why would this be the case?

Comment: @DafyddNZ - Because Discovery is a nonsense

Answer (score 10):

It may be worth noting that Lithium crystals were what was said in dialog in the first episodes of Star Trek "Where No Man has Gone Before" for example.  It was later that it was turned into science fiction with fictional Dilithium.

And further one only needs dilithium if you are heating the warp plasma with an antimatter reaction.  If the plasma can get up to temperature with a more conventional fuel like fusion - the warp coils do not care.  As is often pointed out - TNG era Romulan ships use a microblack hole to heat the plasma.  And TOS Romulan ships apparently used impulse to power the warp drive (and they clearly do have warp capability).

So one is forced to conclude that primitive warp coils and primitive warp plasma work at whatever energy and technology was there - which is not established at all in First Contact.  TNG era warp plasma and coils have no doubt been optimized for what their technology is capable of powering - so we should not make the hurdle higher than necessary for the ship in First Contact.

Regardless "First Contact" does not make much sense from a design perspective.  For example the Warp nacelles don't really need Bussard hydrogen collectors for a 1 minute trip.

Comment: This is what I thought too. Dilithium is not a requirement *per se* for a warp drive, only a prevailing or preferred fuel by the mid-Kirk era. It's like in our own world - most cars run on gasoline or diesel but it's possible to make a car that runs on ethanol, kerosene, jet fuel, bunker oil, or pretty much anything that can burn. Just because very few people today own a car that runs on jet fuel does not mean that a team or society with access to only jet fuel couldn't build a car. It might be more expensive, or even *much* more expensive, but not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Dilithium crystals are used to regulate matter/antimatter reactions aboard starships. However, in *First Contact*, there is no direct evidence that the Phoenix used them... but it DID involve matter-antimatter power generation:

> At one point during the writing of First Contact, the writers of the film considered what might power the matter-antimatter reaction chamber aboard the Phoenix, in lieu of dilithium crystals. Co-writer Ronald D. Moore later recalled, "We had talked about it being from something modified from the thermonuclear warhead – that somehow setting off the fission reaction was what kicked it off." (Star Trek Monthly issue 45, p. 46)
>
> <sub>https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phoenix#Background_information</sub>

So, it's very likely that dilithium crystals weren't used until a later time (during the 50 years humanity was busy recovering from the Third World War, eradicating poverty, disease, etc. - at least according to Counselor Troi from the *First Contact* movie).

During the first 50 years, humanity was primarily focused on self-repair and recovery (growing out of its infancy). Evidently, it wasn't focused solely on that, as development of the warp program was proceeding at a regular pace too during that period, but it seemed to have picked up more speed in the next 40 years (eventually leading to the launch of the NX-01), and it's possible that humanity started using dilithium when they broke the warp two barrier, or prior to that.

So, I'd say that whatever test ships humanity used to reach immediately beyond warp one, they realized they would need a substance to help control matter/antimatter reactions for sustained flights (Cochranes' warp flight was fairly brief and it wouldn't necessarily require dilithium crystals... but if you wanted to use a warp drive for sustained exploration, you'd definitely need a better/more efficient way to regulate matter/antimatter reactions).

Answer (score 2):

After reading various older Star Trek Books including The Final Reflection dilithium is not the fuel source, but a focusing lens.  Starships could travel up to Warp 4 without the dilithium crystals.  A mining accident confirmed the focusing feature of the crystals on matter/anti-matter process, thus allowing faster Warp speeds up to Warp 7 and beyond.

- The Final Reflection by John M Ford

Comment: So how does that tie in to the actual question asked: _"How did Cochrane obtain dilithium for the first warp flight?"_ Also, your answer would benefit from a direct quote from _The Final Reflection_.

Comment: @LogicDictates - is the tie-in not simply that "he didn't need to" ?

Comment: @komodosp - It could very well be -- if I had to guess, I'd say that is what this answer is hinting at -- but I don't think we should be required to guess what the answer's position is on that crucial point. Moreover, even if it did clearly state that Cochrane didn't need dilithium to achieve warp flight, it wouldn't be a complete answer in my eyes without explaining what he used instead, with relevant evidence.

Answer (score 1):

He didn't use dilithium because he didn't need it. Dilithium isn't a power source. Dilithium is used to regulate a matter/anti-matter reaction. The actual fuel source in Star Trek is the energy created by a matter/anti-matter reaction between deuterium and anti-deuterium. The dilithium regulates that reaction. Zefram Cochrane's warp ship used a nuclear reactor from the warhead of the missile that was repurposed. The power source was nuclear not matter/anti-matter.

Comment: The part of your answer that's most directly relevant to the question -- that fact that Cochrane didn't use dilithium, and relied on nuclear power instead -- was already made in [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/233655/122024), and thus didn't really need to be made again, especially without the addition of any new evidence to further reinforce that point.

Comment: He didn't use dilithium INSTEAD OF nuclear power. That would imply that dilithium is used as a power source. It isn't. That was a key point of my answer. Valorum's comment said nuclear power was used to create the "energy required" instead of dilithium "as the power source". Dilithium is not a power source.

Comment: If your intention was to correct a perceived flaw in Valorum's answer, then it would've made more sense to post this as a comment beneath that answer, rather than as a separate answer in itself.

Comment: Because my answer stands on its own as an answer to the original question without really directly relating to the error in someone else's answer. I commented on Valorum's answer as well to directly point out the mistake.

Comment: I'd have an easier time buying that this isn't a further attempt to comment on Valorum's answer if you didn't spend half of it emphasising that dilithium isn't a power source, and that it's merely used to regulate a matter/antimatter reaction. The question never suggested otherwise. On the contrary, it quotes Memory Alpha's explanation of what dilithium is used for, which is consistent with your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

If warp drive was possible without dilithium crystals then star fleet would have never went all in on dilithium warp drive. The fact of the matter is, warp drive require dilithium in order to produce warp field by mixing matter and anti matter in a safe matter. Conventional technology of mixing two in a magnetic confinement resulted in large explosion hence it was required by star fleet to use dilithium crystals. Romulan singluar drive requies a large containment vessel, hence typcial war bird is three times the size of galaxy class star ship. The signular drive containment can fit an entire star ship in it! The power produced by warbird can't never exceed that of the glaxy class. So as to how cochrane did his warp experiment is still up for debate. How was he able to generate that much plasma to generate a warp field is anyone's guess.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve warp. The Federation presumably likes dilithium matter/anti-matter as a power source for a range of reasons, not least that they have a ready supply in their back yard. Other races might not be as lucky

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is incorrect. It has been stated that dilithium doesn't exist on earth so they couldn't have used dilithium. They didn't need dilithium. Dilithium controls the matter/anti-matter reaction and they didn't use a matter/anti-matter reactor. They used a nuclear fusion reactor.